# SettingWithCopyWarning issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a SettingWithCopyWarning in the code. The internet has a lot of solutions but it is still not clear to me.

This is the code

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
df.drop('ID', axis='columns', inplace = True)

df_min = df.loc[(df['Date']<='2014-12') & (df['Date']>='2004-01') & (df['Element']=='TMIN')]
df_min.drop('Element', axis='columns', inplace = True)
```

The last line is giving the 'error'. Why is this and what should be changed in the code?

Using Jupyter - Python3

.copy() is solving the problem but why?

Comment: I think this may be a false positive, but probably `df.loc[ <boolean indexing expression> ].copy()` would remove the warning

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? This should work.

Comment: what is the error ?